# Dynamic way to populate a TreeView in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

I'm currently designing a software that displays accounts in a tree format

I use VS2012 coding is done in VB.NET

I'm using the TreeView control

And I connected my software to a SQL database and the accounts table is as 
follows:

ID - Name - ParentID
1 - Acc01 - 0
2 - Acc02 - 1
3 - Acc03 - 2
and the list goes on...

I know how to create the dataset and I know how to use the node character from the TreeView

but what should I do to code in the list and view it inside the TreeView control properly ?

Keep in mind that my Tree can be in 3 levels , 4 or even more
I need the code to be dynamic

I tried to search and all topics found cover up to 3 levels and inputs each level by it self (which means I have to do 6 times for a 6 level tree and so on ...)

I have used the treeview before but my last case was different I had 3 related tables and used 3 batches of codes to display them as follows:

```
Private Sub CabinetTreeView()
    sqlconnectionstring = 
MainConfig.GetConnectionString(My.Settings.CurrentDB)
    Dim DSCabinet As New DataSet
    Dim CNCabinet As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlconnectionstring)
    Dim DADep As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select GUID,Code+'-'+Name as 
Department,Notes from dep000", CNCabinet)
    Dim DAFolder As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select 
guid,'#'+convert(varchar(255),number)+': '+code+'-'+Name as Folder,DepGuid 
from batch000", CNCabinet)
    Dim DAFiles As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select 
guid,batchguid,DocName from store000", CNCabinet)

    DSCabinet = New DataSet()
    CNCabinet.Open()
    DADep.Fill(DSCabinet, "dtDep")
    DAFolder.Fill(DSCabinet, "dtFolder")
    DAFiles.Fill(DSCabinet, "dtFiles")
    'Close the connection to the data store; free up the resources
    CNCabinet.Close()

    'Create a data relation object to facilitate the relationship between 
the Customers and Orders data tables.
    DSCabinet.Relations.Add("DeptoFold", DSCabinet.Tables("dtDep").Columns("GUID"), DSCabinet.Tables("dtFolder").Columns("DepGuid"))
    DSCabinet.Relations.Add("FoldtoFile", DSCabinet.Tables("dtFolder").Columns("guid"), DSCabinet.Tables("dtFiles").Columns("Batchguid"))

    '''''''''''''''''''''''
    CabinetTree.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim parentrow As DataRow
    Dim ParentTable As DataTable
    ParentTable = DSCabinet.Tables("dtDep")

    For Each parentrow In ParentTable.Rows
        Dim parentnode As TreeNode
        parentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(1).ToString)
        CabinetTree.Nodes.Add(parentnode)
        parentnode.ImageIndex = 0
        parentnode.SelectedImageIndex = 0
        parentnode.Tag = parentrow(0).ToString

        ''''populate child'''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim childrow As DataRow
        Dim childnode As TreeNode
        childnode = New TreeNode()
        For Each childrow In parentrow.GetChildRows("DeptoFold")
            childnode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(childrow(1))
            childnode.Tag = childrow(0).ToString
            childnode.ImageIndex = 1
            childnode.SelectedImageIndex = 2

            ''''populate child2''''
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Dim childrow2 As DataRow
            Dim childnode2 As TreeNode
            childnode2 = New TreeNode()
            For Each childrow2 In childrow.GetChildRows("FoldtoFile")
                childnode2 = childnode.Nodes.Add(childrow2(2))
                childnode2.Tag = childrow2(0).ToString
                childnode2.ImageIndex = 3
                childnode2.SelectedImageIndex = 3

            Next childrow2
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Next childrow
        '''''''''''''''
    Next parentrow

End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance

Best Regards,
Salah Mousa Basha

Comment: This isn't a free coding service, have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry Guys I really searched many times and I updated the Q to inlude this fact